# I have an error to add a root view handler in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, mmdrawercontroller

I am developing an application in which the launch screen is similar to Twitter and I wanted to implement a navigation drawer with MMDrawer, but I have an error that says
"UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency ', reason:' adding a root view controller  as a child of view controller:  '"

I attached the AppDelegate code
I hope you can help me, thank you very much for reading me! regards.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Rodrigo
//
//  Created by expo on 02/03/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Rodrigo. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    var window: UIWindow?
    var drawerContainer:MMDrawerController?



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Personaliza la vista
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window! .backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 34/255, blue: 34/255, alpha:1)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        //Recuerda al usuario
        let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")
        if (userId != nil )
        {

            buildNavigationDrawer()


        }
            //Fin de recordar al usuario

        else{


            //rootViewController from storyboard

            let navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationController")
            self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController


            //logomask
            navigationController.view.layer.mask = CALayer()
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.contents = UIImage(named: "logoGrande500pts")!.cgImage
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 60, height: 60)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.anchorPoint = CGPoint (x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.position = CGPoint (x: navigationController.view.frame.width / 2, y: navigationController.view.frame.height / 2)

            //logo mask background view
            let maskBigView = UIView(frame: navigationController.view.frame)
            maskBigView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            navigationController.view.addSubview(maskBigView)
            navigationController.view.bringSubview(toFront: maskBigView)

            //logo mask animation
            let transformAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation (keyPath: "bounds")
            transformAnimation.duration = 0.5
            transformAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1

            let initalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: (navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds)!)
            let secondBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            let finalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000))

            transformAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
            transformAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
            transformAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)]
            transformAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.add(transformAnimation, forKey: "maskAnimation")

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 1.35, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                           animations: {
                            maskBigView.alpha = 0.0
            },
                           completion: {finished in
                            maskBigView.removeFromSuperview()
            })



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           delay: 1.3,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
                           animations: {
                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)


            },
                           completion: {finished in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                                           delay: 0.0,
                                           options : UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                                           animations: {
                                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                            },
                                           completion: nil
                            )
            })

        }


        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func CAAnimationDelegate (anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool){
        self.window!.rootViewController!.view.layer.mask=nil
    }



    func buildNavigationDrawer(){

        //Personaliza la vista
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window! .backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 34/255, blue: 34/255, alpha:1)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()



        let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        let navigationController:PrincipalViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrincipalViewController") as! PrincipalViewController
        let leftSideMenu:LeftSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController
        let rightSideMenu:RightSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightSideViewController") as! RightSideViewController


        let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigationController)


     window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer
     self.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav


        let leftSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:leftSideMenu)
        let rightSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:rightSideMenu)


        drawerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: mainPageNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideMenuNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightSideMenuNav)

        drawerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
        drawerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView



        /*
         let navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrincipalViewController") as! PrincipalViewController
         let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigationController)
         self.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav
        */

        //logomask
        navigationController.view.layer.mask = CALayer()
        navigationController.view.layer.mask?.contents = UIImage(named: "logoGrande500pts")!.cgImage
        navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 60, height: 60)
        navigationController.view.layer.mask?.anchorPoint = CGPoint (x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        navigationController.view.layer.mask?.position = CGPoint (x: navigationController.view.frame.width / 2, y: navigationController.view.frame.height / 2)
        //logo mask background view
        let maskBigView = UIView(frame: navigationController.view.frame)
        maskBigView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController.view.addSubview(maskBigView)
        navigationController.view.bringSubview(toFront: maskBigView)
        //logo mask animation
        let transformAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation (keyPath: "bounds")
        transformAnimation.duration = 0.5
        transformAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1
        let initalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: (navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds)!)
        let secondBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        let finalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000))
        transformAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
        transformAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
        transformAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)]
        transformAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        navigationController.view.layer.mask?.add(transformAnimation, forKey: "maskAnimation")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 1.35, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                       animations: {
                        maskBigView.alpha = 0.0
        },
                       completion: {finished in
                        maskBigView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 1.3,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
                       animations: {
                        self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
        },
                       completion: {finished in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                                       delay: 0.0,
                                       options : UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                                       animations: {
                                        self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                        },
                                       completion: nil
                        )
        })


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is pretty clear.

The problem is here:

```
window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer
self.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav
```

You are setting the `rootViewController` and then on the very next line, setting it again with something different.

Then, a few lines later, you do this:

```
drawerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: mainPageNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideMenuNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightSideMenuNav)
```

You are taking the `rootViewController` of your window, and trying to add it as a child to another container view controller.

**Obvious fixes:**

1. Remove this line:

   ```
   self.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav
   ```
2. Change the order of the `rootViewController` assignment and `drawerContainer` instantiation. Right now, you are throwing away whatever the original `drawerContainer` was (if it had a value at all).

   ```
   drawerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: mainPageNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideMenuNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightSideMenuNav)
   ```

   needs to come before

   ```
   window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer
   ```

There are probably more problems with your code, but these 2 are issues for sure.

Comment: Hi Dima, I appreciate your response, I tried to do what you recommend,

I removed this line
Self.window? .rootViewController = mainPageNav

And this line
Window? .rootViewController = drawerContainer
I put it right after the key of my function "func buildNavigationDrawer ()"

And when running the application this error arises

"Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(Lldb) "

Comment: I attach screenshot
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3JcX9i_HjjiWTUzdTVCU0ZRMTA

Comment: I don't see `window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer` anywhere in your screenshot.

Comment: I attached Full screenshot
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3JcX9i_HjjiRTZ2ZEZ1T2Y5T28

Comment: `window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer` needs to come **after** you actually create it. You ordered them backwards.

Comment: Just like in the screenshot?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3JcX9i_HjjiMjNEZlpkdllKcEk

Comment: I have it, the only thing I did is that in the function of buildNavigationDrawer () I put all the code that allows me to have a right and left side, and the effect of twitter I put it after the conditional where it stores the data of the user

Answer (score 0):

I enclose my code with the solution

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Expodiseño
//
//  Created by expo on 02/03/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Creategia360. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var drawerContainer:MMDrawerController?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Personaliza la vista
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window! .backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 34/255, blue: 34/255, alpha:1)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        //Recuerda al usuario
        let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")
        if (userId != nil )
        {

            //let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrincipalViewController") as! PrincipalViewController
            let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigationController)
            self.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav

            //logomask
            navigationController.view.layer.mask = CALayer()
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.contents = UIImage(named: "logoGrande500pts")!.cgImage
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 60, height: 60)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.anchorPoint = CGPoint (x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.position = CGPoint (x: navigationController.view.frame.width / 2, y: navigationController.view.frame.height / 2)

            //logo mask background view
            let maskBigView = UIView(frame: navigationController.view.frame)
            maskBigView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            navigationController.view.addSubview(maskBigView)
            navigationController.view.bringSubview(toFront: maskBigView)

            //logo mask animation
            let transformAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation (keyPath: "bounds")
            transformAnimation.duration = 0.5
            transformAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1

            let initalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: (navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds)!)
            let secondBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            let finalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000))

            transformAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
            transformAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
            transformAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)]
            transformAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.add(transformAnimation, forKey: "maskAnimation")

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 1.35, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                           animations: {
                            maskBigView.alpha = 0.0
            },
                           completion: {finished in
                            maskBigView.removeFromSuperview()
            })



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           delay: 1.3,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
                           animations: {
                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)


            },
                           completion: {finished in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                                           delay: 0.0,
                                           options : UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                                           animations: {
                                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                            },
                                           completion: nil
                            )
            })

       buildNavigationDrawer()

        }
            //Fin de recordar al usuario

        else{



            //rootViewController from storyboard

            let navigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationController")
            self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController


            //logomask
            navigationController.view.layer.mask = CALayer()
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.contents = UIImage(named: "logoGrande500pts")!.cgImage
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 60, height: 60)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.anchorPoint = CGPoint (x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.position = CGPoint (x: navigationController.view.frame.width / 2, y: navigationController.view.frame.height / 2)

            //logo mask background view
            let maskBigView = UIView(frame: navigationController.view.frame)
            maskBigView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            navigationController.view.addSubview(maskBigView)
            navigationController.view.bringSubview(toFront: maskBigView)

            //logo mask animation
            let transformAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation (keyPath: "bounds")
            transformAnimation.duration = 0.5
            transformAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1

            let initalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: (navigationController.view.layer.mask?.bounds)!)
            let secondBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            let finalBounds = NSValue(cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000))

            transformAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
            transformAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
            transformAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)]
            transformAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            navigationController.view.layer.mask?.add(transformAnimation, forKey: "maskAnimation")

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 1.35, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                           animations: {
                            maskBigView.alpha = 0.0
            },
                           completion: {finished in
                            maskBigView.removeFromSuperview()
            })



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                           delay: 1.3,
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptions(),
                           animations: {
                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)


            },
                           completion: {finished in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                                           delay: 0.0,
                                           options : UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                                           animations: {
                                            self.window!.rootViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                            },
                                           completion: nil
                            )
            })

        }


        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func CAAnimationDelegate (anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool){
        self.window!.rootViewController!.view.layer.mask=nil
    }

    func buildNavigationDrawer(){

        let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        let navigationController:PrincipalViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrincipalViewController") as! PrincipalViewController
        let leftSideMenu:LeftSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController
        let rightSideMenu:RightSideViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightSideViewController") as! RightSideViewController


        let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigationController)
        let leftSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:leftSideMenu)
        let rightSideMenuNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:rightSideMenu)


        //  self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        drawerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: mainPageNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideMenuNav, rightDrawerViewController: rightSideMenuNav)

        drawerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
        drawerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView

        window?.rootViewController = drawerContainer
        //self.window?.rootViewController = mainPageNav

    }

}
```